# Magento 1.9 How to find the physical file location from $this->geturl

Tags: magento-1.9, geturl

In Magento, I often see this code from different modules.
for example

```
 'url' = $this->geturl('*/path/to/file',array('_forced_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure()))
```

But how can I find out which file on the server is being called from geturl? the path given in the code is not the physical path to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `path/to/file` take a look at this:

```
$this->geturl('module/controller/action')
```

or

```
$this->geturl('catalog/product/view')
```

- `module` gives you a first hint, where to search. For expample if it's `catalog`, you'll find the controller in `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers`
- `controller` is a php file inside modules controller folder, in this case `ProductController.php`
- `action` is a method inside this controller file, like `viewAction()`

Answer (score 2):

From `getUrl` Magento  call a particular action of a module's controller. the syntax in function is like `getUrl('modulename/controller/action')`

for example if you use `getUrl('customer/account/create')` then it will call Customer module's `AccountController.php` file and in this file it call `createAction` function.

To locate file you have to go to `app/code/CodePool/Namespace/ModuleName/controllers/`

for the given example of `customer/account/create` you will find the file at `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`

Answer (score 0):

Inside app/Mage.php

```
public static function getUrl($route = '', $params = array())
    {
        return self::getModel('core/url')->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
```

Which in turns go inside `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Url.php` and call `getUrl().` And you need to pass `frontname/controllerName/actionName` not `modulename`. `frontname` gets defined inside `config.xml` for any module.